# Snowflake java (kotlin) use ST_INTERSECTS geospatial

Tags: java, dataframe, geometry, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a problem. I am trying to use geographical functions from snowflake in my kotlin code. Usualy, it is common to use Functions from com.snowflake.snowpark_java.Functions, and use the funciton you want to filter your query with.
The [ST_INTERSECTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/st_intersects#usage-notes)  function seems to not have its implementation in the Functions package. I didn't find any other way to use it.
I want to pass it as parameters the geographical column, and the searchEnvelope that is returned by snowflake. The goal is to add the ST_INTERSECTS to my dataframe in a WHERE clause like so :
`val dataFrame = snowparkSession.table(tableName) .where(ST_INTERSECTS(columnName, envelope)) .select(*)`

I tried doing this :
`Functions.callUDF("ST_INTERSECTS", geometryAttributeColumn)`
since  it is what was recommended here : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/java/calling-functions
But it awaits 2 columns attributes, and my envelope isn't one or doesn't contain one. It simply contains the Geometry Attribute Name and the search Envelope, which is a rectangle

Comment: What if you try raw SQL directly like `val dataFrame = snowparkSession.sql(SELECT ST_INTERSECTS(columnName, envelope))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it thanks to @Sergiu. I did in fact use Functions.sqlExpr and it worked !
For those mondering, you can transform your envelope to a generic WKTUtilities with WKTUtilities.toWKT(envelope). This can then be sent to a geometric attribute name like so : `Functions.sqlExpr("$spatialFunction(\"$geometryAttributeName\", ST_GEOGRAPHYFROMWKT(\'$geometryWKT\'))")` (in Kotlin)